# Conditional formatting for strings with grep in kable

Tags: r, kable

Using `cell_spec` it is possible to conditionally format numeric cells in a `kable` table based on value, but is there a way to format cells based on patterns within a string?

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(x = c("bbb", "bba", "bbb"), y = c(-7, -7, 7)) %>%
  mutate(x = cell_spec(x, "html", color = ifelse(grep("a", x), "red", "black"))) %>%
  mutate(y = cell_spec(y, "html", color = ifelse(y < 0, "red", "black")))

kable(df, "html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("striped")
```

Using `grep` in the code above turns the entire column red, while I would like only the cells that contain "a" to be red. This process works for the numeric values in column "y".
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grepl` instead of `grep` as `grepl` returns a logical vector whereas `grep` returns index of match and `ifelse` expects a logical vector .

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(x = c("bbb", "bba", "bbb"), y = c(-7, -7, 7)) %>%
 mutate(x = cell_spec(x, "html",color = ifelse(grepl("a", x), "red", "black"))) %>%
 mutate(y = cell_spec(y, "html", color = ifelse(y < 0, "red", "black")))


kable(df, "html", escape = F) %>% kable_styling("striped")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to `?ifelse`, the usage is

> ifelse(test, yes, no)

and

> test - an object which can be coerced to logical mode.

With `grep`, the numeric indices are returned based on `?grep`

> value - if FALSE, a vector containing the (integer) indices of the matches determined by grep is returned, and if TRUE, a vector containing the matching elements themselves is returned.

So, definitely, the input for `ifelse` 'test' is not matched with the output from `grep`.

If we wanted to use `grep`, we can use `replace`, where the usage is

> replace(x, list, values)
>
> list - an index vector

-code

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c("bbb", "bba", "bbb"), y = c(-7, -7, 7)) %>%
     mutate(x = cell_spec(x, "html", 
               color = replace(rep("black", n()), grep("a", x), "red")), 
            y = cell_spec(y, "html", 
               color = ifelse(y < 0, "red", "black")))

kable(df, "html", escape = F) %>% kable_styling("striped")
```

-output

[image]